# How to convert the following if conditions to Linear integer programming constraints?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

These are the conditions:

```
if(x > 0)
{
    y >= a;
    z <= b;
}
```

It is quite easy to convert the conditions into Linear Programming constraints if **x** were binary variable. But I am not finding a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in 2 steps

#### Step 1: Introduce a binary dummy variable

Since `x` is continuous, we can introduce a **binary** `0/1` dummy variable. Let's call it `x_positive`

if `x>0` then we want `x_positive =1`. We can achieve that via the following constraint, where `M` is a very large number.

```
x < x_positive * M
```

Note that this forces x_positive to become 1, if x is itself positive. If x is negative, `x_positive` can be anything. (We can force it to be zero by adding it to the objective function with a tiny penalty of the appropriate sign.)

#### Step 2: Use the dummy variable to implement the next 2 constraints

In English: if `x_positive = 1`, then `y >= a`

However, if `x_positive = 0`, y can be anything (`y > -inf`)

```
y > a - M (1 - x_positive)
```

Similarly,

if `x_positive = 1`, then `z <= b`

```
z <= b + M * (1 - x_positive)
```

Both the linear constraints above will kick in if x>0 and will be trivially satisfied if x <=0.